# Get elements from string

Tags: c, c-strings

I'm stumped in a rather trivial thing... 
So, basically I want the "words" between the first one and the last one to go to data and the last one to go to key.

C-POSIX only, pls.

Is strtok_r the way to go or I'm way off on this? Something else?

```
char *key = NULL, *data=NULL, *save=NULL;
char comando[1024];
fgets(comando, 512, stdin);

strtok_r(comando, " ",&save);

while(strcmp(save,"\n")){
    strcat(data,strtok_r(NULL," ",&save));
}

key = strtok_r(NULL, "\n",&save);
```

P.S: comando is 1024 as memory is not a problem and better safe than sorry. fgets reads 512 'cause that's the char line limit on standard unix terminal.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Maybe print some output, like what `save` is pointing to after each call to `strtok_r()`

Comment: I think using `strtok_r` is okay...or is anything going wrong?

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `data` and  `key`. Right now you are appending to a null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will crash on this line:

```
strcat(data,strtok_r(NULL," ",&save));
```

Because you never reserved space for `data`. `strcat` will try to write to a `NULL` memory address.

Another thing to note is that you shouldn't rely on `save` to check for the end of the line. According to `strtok`'s manpage:

> The saveptr argument is a pointer to a char * variable that is used
>   internally by strtok_r() in order to maintain context between
>   successive calls that parse the same string.

Relying on the value of `saveptr` outside of `strtok_r` breaks the abstraction layer, you shouldn't assume anything about how `strtok` uses `saveptr`. It's bad practice.

A slightly better approach is to keep a pointer to the previous token returned by `strtok`, and a pointer to the current token. When `strtok` returns NULL, meaning there are no more tokens, then `prev` will point to the last token, which is your `key`. Here's some code:

```
char *key = NULL, *save=NULL;
char *prev, *curr;
char comando[1024];
char data[1024];

data[0] = '\0';
fgets(comando, 512, stdin);
prev = curr = strtok_r(comando, " ",&save);

while (curr != NULL) {
    prev = curr;
    curr = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &save);
    if (curr != NULL)
        strcat(data, prev);
}

key = prev;
```

Note that I allocated space for `data` by declaring it as array instead of pointer. The instruction

```
data[0] = '\0';
```

is there to make sure that `strcat` finds the null terminating byte in the first call.

You can replace the use of `prev` directly by `key`, I left it that way to make the code more readable.

A word of advice: always remember that `strtok` modifies its argument destructively (you lose the identity of the delimiting bytes), and that you can't call it with constant strings.

**Note:** `data` will contain every word concatenated. You lose the spaces. I'm not sure if this is what you want. If it's not, you might want to use something better than `strcat` (which is not very efficient, btw). For example, you code use `sprintf` to print the token into `data` with a leading space, and keep a pointer to the next free position in `data`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to replace your loop with a following code (printf() is used just for testing):

```
strtok_r(comando, " ", &save);
char *res = NULL;
while (NULL != (res = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &save))) {
  if (key != NULL) {
    //strcat(data, key); // FIXME
    printf("data = %s\n", key);
  }
  key = res;
}
printf("key = %s\n", key);
```

Also strcat() should not be used with NULL arguments - it leads to a crash. So data pointer should be pointing to some array. Results of the running of the code:

```
┌─(16:08:22)─(michael@lorry)─(~/tmp/strtok)
└─► gcc -o main main.c; echo "one two three four five" | ./main
data=two
data=three
data=four
key = five
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots wrong with your code

```
char *key = NULL, *data=NULL, *save=NULL;
```

Later on, you are using `strcat` to add strings to `data` but you have allocated no storage to `data`.  That will cause a segmentation fault.

```
fgets(comando, 512, stdin);
```

`fgets` will read at most one less than the number passed to it.  So, if the user does type in 512 characters, the string will have no terminating `\n`.  Also, the only way to detect an error or end of file is to check the return result of `fgets`.  If it's NULL either you have reached end of file (user has hit ctrl-d) or there is an error.  In either case, the content of your buffer is indeterminate.

```
while(strcmp(save,"\n"))
```

I don't think you are allowed to rely on the assumption that your `save` pointer will point to the rest of the unconsumed string.

```
strtok_r(comando, " ",&save);
```

`strtok_r` signals that it has reached the end of the data by returning a `NULL` pointer.  You can't throw away the return result without looking at it.  Also, this will consume the trailing `\n` as part of the last token.

```
strcat(data,strtok_r(NULL," ",&save));
```

As I said before, `data` is a null pointer.  Also, `strtok_r` can return `NULL`

I would do something more like:

```
char* currentTok = strtok_r(commando, " \n", &save); // separator is space or \n
char* previousTok = NULL;
while (currentTok != NULL)
{
    if (previousTok != NULL)
    {
        // save previousTok in data unless its the first token
    }
    previousTok = currentTok;
    currentTok = strtok_r(NULL, " \n", &save);
}
char* key = previousTok;
```